# How do I add a file to a TextMate project from the command line?

Tags: applescript, textmate

I'd like to be able to add a file to a Textmate project (which is currently open) from the command line. Is there a way to do it (maybe via Applescript, the `mate` command, directly editing the project file, etc.)?

Comment: why do you want to do this through the command line ?

Comment: @mcgrailm I do development on a remote server and find it convenient to be able to type `mate filename` to open a file. Since I work on multiple feature branches, I'm trying a new workflow where I have one project file per feature branch, but it's a pain to have to drag files into the project with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample TextMate project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>documents</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>bar.c</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>foo.c</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>../src/c/linkedlist.c</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>fileHierarchyDrawerWidth</key>
    <integer>265</integer>
    <key>metaData</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>showFileHierarchyDrawer</key>
    <true/>
    <key>windowFrame</key>
    <string>{{282, 3}, {1148, 875}}</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

All you need to do is create a command-line tool which adds the following information:

```
        <dict>
            <key>filename</key>
            <string>PATH_TO_FILENAME</string>
        </dict>
```

Don't forget to replace PATH_TO_FILENAME with real path. Normally, I would write the script to illustrate my point, but since I don't have time, I can only offer this suggestion instead.

Comment: I've tried this. Unfortunately, this doesn't do anything to a running Textmate instance. I could close the project window, edit the file, then re-open, but that would fail if I have unsaved files. Is there a way to get a running Textmate to re-load the project file?

Comment: @Evan Krall: I don't know of a way to automate this, sorry.